# How to implement a customized DataLoader that inherits pytorch's one?

Tags: python, pytorch, implementation, torch

I need to implement a customized DataLoader, that inherits from torch.data.utils.DataLoader.

I have searched it for half hour, but there is no example or doc about this.

What methods of it should I implement? and what types should I return in them?
Is there any official docs about this?

Does anyone would pls give me a hint?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate a bit more about your use case. I am curious why a custom implementation of `torch.utils.data.Dataset` will not work for you .